# ListBox: How to detect compression (end of scroll) states in WinRT (WP8.1)?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am working on a WinRT-based Windows Phone 8.1 app.

How can I detect or receive a notification when the user has scrolled a ListBox to its end?

Comment: Expand out acronyms, reword slightly.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
I know this may be an old topic but today I just happened to be in the same boat, so here is what I came up with.

Just wrapped the `ListBox` around a `ScrollViewer` and made a `viewChanged` event handler to get what I need.

In this case I made the event fire the "Load more data" when the user is almost at the end of the ScrollViewer

**UI**

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ViewChanged="yourEvent_ViewChanged">
    <ListBox x:Name="ResultsListBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
    </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
private void yourEvent_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as ScrollViewer).VerticalOffset >= ((sender as ScrollViewer).ScrollableHeight - (sender as ScrollViewer).ViewportHeight / 4))
    {
        // Do your "Load more data" work here
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try pulling out scrollviewer from listview and use following methods

Code behind:

```html
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<String> Collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private bool incall;
    private int offset;
    int _noofelements;
    ScrollViewer _scrollViewer;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        listview.ItemsSource = Collection;
        addNumber(0);
    }

    public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
    {
        if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);

            var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void OnViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer view = (ScrollViewer)sender;
        if ((view.VerticalOffset > 0.9 * view.ScrollableHeight) & !incall)
        {
            incall = true;
            addNumber(++offset);
        }
    }

    private void addNumber(int offset)
    {
        int start = offset * 20;
        for (int i = start; i < start + 20; i++)
        {
            if (i % 20 == 0)
                Collection.Insert(0, (_noofelements++).ToString());
            else
                Collection.Add((_noofelements++).ToString());
        }

        incall = false;
    }

    private void listview_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _scrollViewer = GetScrollViewer(listview);
        if (_scrollViewer != null)
        {
            _scrollViewer.ViewChanged += OnViewChanged;
        }
    }
```

Ui:

```html
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listview" Loaded="listview_Loaded">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel ItemsUpdatingScrollMode="KeepItemsInView"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Margin="25" FontSize="32" Text="{Binding}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Try replacing ListView with Listbox and it will work.